# iOS: UIImagePNGRepresentation().writeToFile not writing to intended directory

Tags: ios, image, file, swift

Using `Swift` I am trying to download a `JPG` from a URL and then saving that image to a file, but when I try to save it to a different directory it won't. It will download to the app's `Documents` folder, but not when I try to set the path to another subfolder.

```
let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("SubDirectory") as String
let filepath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.jpg")
UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(data: data)).writeToFile(filepath, atomically: true)
```

When I run this, it doesn't save the image to it? Why is this happening? Do I need to create the subfolder beforehand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Does the subdirectory folder already exist? If not, you have to create it first. And it's now advisable to use `NSURL` instead of path strings. So that yields:

   ```
   let filename = "test.jpg"
   let subfolder = "SubDirectory"

   do {
       let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
       let documentsURL = try fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
       let folderURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(subfolder)
       if !folderURL.checkPromisedItemIsReachableAndReturnError(nil) {
           try fileManager.createDirectoryAtURL(folderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
       }
       let fileURL = folderURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename)

       try imageData.writeToURL(fileURL, options: .AtomicWrite)
   } catch {
       print(error)
   }
   ```
2. I would advise against converting the `NSData` to a `UIImage`, and then converting it back to a `NSData`. You can just write the original `NSData` object directly if you want.

   The process of round-tripping this through a `UIImage` can make lose quality and/or metadata, potentially making the resulting asset larger, etc. One should generally use the original `NSData` where possible.

Comment: Thanks! This explains a lot. Your code has been very helpful. And the reason I am converting to an `Image` is that if I don't have this image already in the file system, I would download it and load it into an `ImageView`.

Comment: Fine, if you need `UIImage` for other reasons, go ahead an instantiate one. I'm just advising against subsequently re-extracting `NSData` in PNG format unless you have compelling reason to do so. (a) it's slower; (b) the file could be bigger (esp if original image was JPEG); (c) you're stripping out meta data; etc. If you really want/need to do PNG conversion, feel free, but make sure you have compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Duly noted. Understandable. Makes sense to not convert data if not necessary. I made adjustments in my code to keep the `NSData` as `NSData` when saving to the file. But I do convert to `UIImage` when displaying it. Thanks for the help!